# Instagram Invalid Access token for non-expired token

Tags: api, oauth, oauth-2.0, instagram

I'm building a simple app to hit the Instagram API and display pictures. Following their [docs](https://www.instagram.com/developer/authentication/), I redirect users to a sign-in, after which they're sent back to the app with an `access_token`. When I use that token to make requests, however, I get the following response:

```
{
  "meta": {
    "error_type": "OAuthAccessTokenException",
    "code": 400,
    "error_message": "The access_token provided is invalid."
  }
}
```

The requested URL is:

```
"https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/search?lat=37.7936981&lng=-122.3966248&access_token=12345.adsf123adsf2341adsfasdfwhatever"
```

> I've also tried putting the token within quotations, and URI-escaping the ampersands.

And I've tried this both through a `script` tag `src` and as a GET request in Postman. Unlike most of the answers I've found related to the above error, this is definitely not an expired token issue, as I run into this error immediately after getting the token. And it also appears NOT to be a case of my passing the token incorrectly, because when I remove the token altogether, I get a separate error complaining that no token or client_id has been passed.

Anyone familiar with this error? Have a sense what I might be doing wrong?